# Moving domain to subdirectory with CPanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cpanel

I recently moved several of my domains to GoDaddy, and am currently struggling to get the directory structure properly set up with each of them. I have each of my addon domains in its own directory under public_html/. Additionally, I want to move my primary domain into its own subfolder for cleanliness. As a result, my directory setup looks like this:

```
public_html/
    primarydomain/
    addondomainA/
    addondomainB/
    addondomainC/
```

I setup my .htaccess file under public_html as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite direct addondomain access to their proper domains
RedirectMatch ^/addondomainA.com/(.*)$ http://addondomainA.com/$1 
RedirectMatch ^/addondomainB.com/(.*)$ http://addondomainB.com/$1 
RedirectMatch ^/addondomainC.com/(.*)$ http://addondomainC.com/$1

# Rewrite primary domain access to the primarydomain/ folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?primarydomain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/primarydomain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /primarydomain/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?primarydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ primarydomain/index.html [L]
```

The addon domain redirects work perfectly, and if I try to access primarydomain.com, the request is properly rewritten to the primarydomain/ subdirectory. However, if I try to access primarydomain.com/primarydomain, nothing gets rewritten (as far as I can tell) and the user can directly access the page. I would like to disallow all direct access requests for the primarydomain/ folder, but nothing I try seems to work. I thought that removing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/primarydomain/
```

Would do something, but it seems to have no effect on the behavior. Similarly, both:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

...seem to have no effect if deleted. I even tried adding a fourth RedirectMatch clause up top, hoping to catch the folder name if it's inserted, but it leads to a redirect loop, as if it's processing the commands out of order. I've devoured all the answers I could find on stack overflow, but none of them solve the issue. I've tried multiple fresh browsers, and am pretty certain that this is not a cache problem.

Does anybody have any ideas how to accomplish this seemingly super-basic task? Is there something I've overlooked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a cname back to the proper directory (cname in advanced dns in cPanel)